# expressjs database query using user id?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    select(req.params.id, res); 
});

function select(id, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = ?' , function(err, rows){
        res.render('users', {users : rows});
    });
}
```

and here is my users.jade:

```
html
    head
    title Welcome

    body
    #container
        - each user in users
            p=user.name+':'+user.number
```

I am just trying to do select query using the id. The SQL table just has fields name, number, /user/tom for example would just spit out Tom:11 on a page or something.

I get the error "cannot ready property 'length' of undefined, so am assuming something is wrong with how I set up the query. Am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function select(id, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE number = "'+id+'"' , function(err, rows){
        res.render('users', {users : rows});
    });
}
```

assuming number is what you mean by id.
you are getting that error because row is undefined because nothing is returned and err is most likely an error.

I like to use something like this:

```
if(err || row==undefined){ your_handle_error_function(); return; }
```

to avoid this

Comment: ah! thank you! i just discovered the "?" syntax is actually from php. :P clearly new to all of this. appreciate it.